# How to save data into a file using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("src/driver/chromedriver", "G:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/tables");

    WebElement table;

    table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div"));
    String dataoutput;
    dataoutput = table.getText();
    System.out.println(dataoutput);

    String csvOutputFile = "table.csv";

    File filedata = new File("src/main/table.csv");
    if (filedata.exists() && !filedata.isFile()) {
        FileWriter writecsv = new FileWriter("src/main/table.csv");
        String datas = dataoutput;
        writecsv.append(dataoutput)
    }
}
```

This is my code but it isn't saving data to file.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(dataoutput);` line print.

Comment: that prints out the text it finds from web element into the console, i want that saved into a csv file

Comment: Can you try with `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(dataoutput);`

Comment: in place of `test.csv` place your path for csv file.

Comment: you want to add in a txt file or in csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
    driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/tables");

    WebElement table;

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    table = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div")));
    String dataoutput;
    dataoutput = table.getText();
    System.out.println(dataoutput);

    String csvOutputFile = "table.csv";

    try(FileWriter writecsv = new FileWriter("src/main/table.csv")) {
        writecsv.append(dataoutput);
    }
```

1. File checking is removed, as we are creating a new file here.
2. Added explicit wait using WebDriverWait, to wait for the table element to be displayed.
3. kept FileWriter inside try block as it was giving compilation issues for me. The good thing with this syntax is it automatically closed the fileWriter object.

Answer (score 0):

Data is not saved in the file due to the below reasons. Please use the below modified (working )code.

1. In if condition, `!filedata.isFile()` is added and it is always false.So, it needs to be changed as `filedata.isFile()`
2. `FileWriter` object is not closed and it needs to be closed after doing the append action
3. As a best practice, add some wait after launching a URL.otherwise, element will not find correctly and `NoSuchElementException` exception will be thrown

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("src/driver/chromedriver", "G:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/tables");

    //Wait is addeded for the Page Load completion 
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Premier"));


    WebElement table;

    table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div"));

    String dataoutput = table.getText();
    System.out.println(dataoutput);


    File filedata = new File("src/main/table.csv");

    //Not Equal condition is modified
    if (filedata.exists() && filedata.isFile()) {
        FileWriter writecsv = new FileWriter(filedata);
        String datas = dataoutput;
        writecsv.append(dataoutput)
        writecsv.close();
    }
}
```